# Replace scene goes on increasing memory usage and memory leak too how to handle that? or How should I enable ARC in my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, out-of-memory

I am working on a cocos2d project which is a game with many scenes. 
When I call replace scene ,I use

```
[scene2 removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
```

In the dealloc method.
Also, I have removed all the unused spritesheets by using

```
    NSString *PngName = [atlas.AtlasName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSString *PlistName = [atlas.AtlasName stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:PlistName];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrameByName:PngName];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
```

When I check the description of my

```
[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
```

, It shows me that it removes the unused spritesheets but it does not free the memory when I check on device with Instrumets. This results in app crash.

After many trials I thought of using ARC in my project but when I convert it to ARC project even after following steps shown in

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Klj9xRafog4

I get many errors in my CCArray, CCDirectorIOS etc.. 
Can anybody help me to solve this issue??

Comment: `When I check the description`, how did you check it ?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]description]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are removing your touch delegate when you are changing scenes.

Comment: Thanks I had forgot it but after doing that too it does keep eating the momory

Comment: Can we see how you are doing this?  I had this exact same problem a few weeks ago and this was the culprit for me.  After 3-4 scene changes, I'd completely run out of memory.

Comment: Yes this is. can you please guide me how did you overcome this problem?

Comment: I overcame it by releasing the touch delegate onexit.   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];

Answer (score 0):

Try using `purgeSharedSpriteFrameCache` of `CCSpriteFrameCache` and `removeUnusedSpriteFrames` and `removeUnusedTextures`. Have a look at these threads for more details:

1. [Release all texture memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865356/release-all-texture-memory)
2. [Correct way to remove sprite cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455884/cocos2d-ios-what-is-the-correct-way-to-remove-sprites-from-cache)

Hope it helps!

Comment: it removes the unused textures but when I try to reload the previous  scene, It gives me error of invalid sprite frame name since it can not access the texture..

Comment: Since you releases the memory you need to re-create resources back when needed (like going back to previous screen)

Comment: I cleared the texturecache also the spriteframe cache but still it goes eating up memory. I feel Im really stuck.